# Plot a histogram according to a set of rules using data from two tables

Tags: list-manipulation, histograms

Let's say I have two Tables `A={1.0,2.3,1.5,3.0,1.1,}` , `B={2,10,3,1,0}` and I'd like to plot a histogram in the following way:

1. Divide the range of values of `A` into `N` bins of equal length `(Max[A]-Min[A])/N`.
2. There will be some number of "points" (number of corresponding entries of `A`) in each bin. Count the number of points in each of the bins for which the **corresponding** entries of `B` lie between some values `minB` and `maxB`.
3. Plot the resulting distribution of points in the bins.

Let's see how it works with the data given.

`Max[A]=3.0`, `Min[A]=1.0`, choose `N = 2` (the choice is compeletly arbitrary). The width of the bin is 1. The first bin has three "points", because the values `A[[1]]`, `A[[3]]` and `A[[5]]` lie between 1.0 and 2.0. The second bin has two "points", because the values `A[[2]]` and `A[[4]]` lie between 2.0 and 3.0.

Now, choose `minB=1`, `maxB=3` (again, arbitrarily). Then, out of three "points" in the first bin only `i=1` and `i=3` work, but not `i=5`, because the corresponding value of `B[[5]]` is outside of the closed interval $[minB,maxB]$. Out of two "points" in the second bin only `i=4` works, but not `i=2`, because the corresponding value of `B[[2]]` is outside of the closed interval $[minB,maxB]$.

Thus the distribution is such that there are two points in the first bin and one point in the second bin.

How do I plot this histogram given `A` and `B`?

**UPDATE:** The problem arose while simulating the production of a neutrino beam. In the actual problem `A` are energies of the neutrinos and `B` are off-axis angles. I faked `A` and `B` to make it look simpler. This is the first time I'm using Mathematica in my research, so it takes hours to figure out things that other people can do in 2 minutes.

**UPDATE2** Some possible data and corresponding outputs.

DATA: `A={1,2,3,4,5}` , `B={1,2,3,4,5}`, `N=2`, `minB=1`, `maxB=3`, $bin1=[1,3)$, $bin2=[3,5]$ (note the open and closed intervals).

OUTPUT: `bin1={2 points}`, `bin2={1 point}`.

DATA: `A={1,2,3,4,5}` , `B={1,2,3,4,5}`, `N=4`, `minB=1`, `maxB=3`, $bin1=[1,2)$, $bin2=[2,3)$, $bin3=[3,4)$, $bin4=[4,5]$ (note the open and closed intervals).

OUTPUT: `bin1={1 points}`, `bin2={1 point}`, `bin3={1 point}`, `bin4={0 points}`.

Comment: You should consider less inlined code,  which makes evaluation cumbersome. Larger, separated code blocks are more convenient.

Comment: I deleted my answer as I'm confused by your example `BinLists[A, (maxA - minA)/Length[A]]` is a possible starting point, then possibly followed by usage of `Select` and `Position` in some way.

Comment: @Histograms, what exactly are you confused about?

Comment: @Physicsworks I updated my answer , I think I have it now. If you provide the expected result for larger data (A,B) and a larger bin-count, I could verify it or correct it.

Answer (score 1):

New answer using [`BinLists`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinLists.html)

```
A = {1.0, 2.3, 1.5, 3.0, 1.1};
B = {2, 10, 3, 1, 0};
nbins = 2;
AIdx = Transpose[{A, Range[Length[A]]}];

(* AIdx contains {{{1., 1}, {1.5, 3}, {1.1, 5}}, {{2.3, 2}, {3., 4}}}
corresponding to
{{A[[1]],A[[3]],A[[5]]},
 {A[[2]],A[[4]]}} as value/index pairs *)

{minA, maxA} = {Min[A], Max[A]};
{minB, maxB} = {1, 3};
firstHistIndexed = Flatten[#, 1] & /@ BinLists[AIdx, (maxA - minA)/(nbins - 1), 1];

finalHist = 
 Function[{sub}, 
  Select[sub, minB <= B[[#[[2]]]] <= maxB &][[All, 1]]] /@ firstHistIndexed

(* Results: {{1., 1.5}, {3.}}  *)

finalHistCounts = Length /@ finalHist

(* Results: {2, 1}  *)
```

Ok, please clarify if this works. First it takes `A` and creates pairs of elements with their index. Then it bins these by their value (index kept in second position). You can replace `(maxA-minA)/(nbins-1)` with a different bin width if you want.

Then from each `{value,index}` pair in the binning of `A`, it finds elements of `B` (using the index) which fall into the range `minB,maxB`, it does this for all bins. Lastly we remove indices which you no longer need with `[[All,1]]`. The `finalHistCounts` is the number of elements of `A` in some bin of `A` that also have elements `b` of `B` with the same index and this `b` in `B` is in the `minB,maxB` range.

Comment: I haven't got the plot (#3) yet, I need to sleep :P

Comment: I've added some data for you to check. Could you add a code that makes a histogram?

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this help?

```
A = {1.0, 2.3, 1.5, 3.0, 1.1};
B = {2, 10, 3, 1, 0} ;

minB = 1;
maxB = 3;

Histogram[Pick[A, minB <= # <= maxB & /@ B], 2]
```

[image: histogram]

**UPDATE**: 
This part does the *filtering*:

```
filteredA = Pick[A, minB <= # <= maxB & /@ B]
```

I assumed the binning was straightforward and didn't try to make it pretty. Here's a better job (but not a general solution):

```
Histogram[filteredA, {{1, 2, 3 + 10^-6}}, Ticks -> {Range[1, 3], Range[0, 2]}]
```

[image]

Notice I added a small amount the upper bound of the final bin in order to capture the largest observation. This is an issue when you have observations on the bin boundaries.

Comment: Thanks, but the first bin should go from Min[A] to (Max[A]+Min[A])/2 and the second from (Max[A]+Min[B])/2 to Max[A]. Without this, I can't tell whether your neat method works or not.

Comment: @Physicsworks I've addressed that (at least partially) in the edit to my answer. Depending on your data, you may not have the issue with observations that equal bin boundaries.